# Implement UIPickerview on Mobile Safari via HTML

Tags: mobile, safari, uipickerview

Is there a way to create some effects similar to the UIPickerView on Iphone Mobile Safari via HTML/javascript/css?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="myPicker" name="myPicker">
    <option value="" default selected">Pick a value</option>
    <option value="pick1">Pick 1</option>
    <option value="pick1">Pick 2</option>
</select>
```